# Why isn't the finally getting executed?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch, try-finally

It was my assumption that the finally block always gets executed as long as the program is running.  However, in this console app, the finally block does not seem to get executed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("finally");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

[image: Result]

Note: When the exception was thrown, windows askmed me if I wanted to end the appliation, I said 'Yes.'

Comment: Click `no` and see what happens

Comment: run it from the command line instead of within your IDE

Comment: It's look very strange. 'finally' should be wrote exactly after StackTrace.

Comment: there is no catch, the exception is unhandled and the app quits

Comment: Ilya - There is no option to hit no.  The other option is to "debug".  Kevin - it is running from the command line, not the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the "ConsoleApplication1" has stopped responding, you have two choices.

[image: Windows Error Reporting dialog]

If you press cancel, the unhandled exception is allowed to continue until eventually the application is terminated.  This allows the `finally` block to execute.  If you do not press cancel then [Windows Error Reporting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Error_Reporting)  halts the process, collects a minidump and then terminates the application.  This means the `finally` block is not executed.

Alternatively, if you handle the exception in a higher method you will definitely see the `finally` block.  For example:

```
static void unhandled()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("finally");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper;
    try
    {
        unhandled();
    }
    catch ( Exception )
    {
        // squash it
    }
}
```

Always gives the output "finally"

Answer (score 6):

It executed actually. Just you didn't notice. Just when you see `Windows is checking for a solution to the problem` click <kbd>Cancel</kbd> and see it.

[image]

Comment: What environment are you running in?  I am using windows 7, 64.  When it asks you "Windows is checking for a solution to the problem.." don't click cancel.  Let it do its thing.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you are debugging and when you click no, the execution is being halted by the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

When running from command line. Just when Windows tries to end application gracefully click `no` or `cancel` if application is not responding. 
[image]

Comment: What environment are you running in? I am using windows 7, 64. When it asks you "Windows is checking for a solution to the problem.." don't click cancel. Let it do its thing.

Comment: Then Windows will terminate application without letting it to print to console

Answer (score -2):

An exception bubbles up the stack until it finds a handler. If it doesn't, the program exits. That's the case in your scenario... there's no handler, so the program exits before it hits the finally block.

Comment: -1 – `finally` should be executed *before* bubbling up the stack – in fact, *during* the stack unwinding.

Comment: the entire purpose of finally apparently loses its use if there isnt a catch? thats a new one on me :L

Comment: Sorry, it was a thoughtless answer.